# How to get the type of an EVP_PKEY?

Tags: openssl

In an old program we have a line of code like below:

```
EVP_PKEY *pKey;
/*
.
.
*/
if (pkey->type == EVP_PKEY_RSA)
    doSomething();
```

But in newer versions of OpenSSL the access to internal implementation of `EVP_PKEY` is banned.
I could not find any function to replace above implementation. Any idea?

Comment: FYI... there's also an `EVP_PKEY_RSA2`. But [`EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA.html) man pages says. *"... the use of alternative non-standard OIDs is now rare so `EVP_PKEY_RSA2` (et al) are not often seen in practice"*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer on OpenSSL Github [issue list:](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1779#issuecomment-266495200)

> EVP_PKEY_id() returns the type field.

Comment: Yeah, its not the most memorable name for the function. I seem to recall a bug report that suggested `EVP_PKEY_type` that also checked arguments to avoid the NULL dereference. Nothing came of it.

Comment: There is also EVP_PKEY_base_id(), which is actually what should be used, I think. This avoids the problem that "historically keys using the same algorithm could use different OIDs" (as per the documentation).